# Enum type with class body and data

Tags: java, enums

```
enum BankOperation { PLUS, MINUS }

public BankOperation getBankOperation(int oldAmount, int newAmount) {
    BankOperation operation = newAmount >= oldAmount ? BankOperation.PLUS : BankOperation.MINUS;
    int delta = Math.abs(newAmount - oldAmount);
    switch (operation) {
        case PLUS:
            System.out.println(String.format("Adding %s dollars", delta));
            break;
        case MINUS:
            System.out.println(String.format("Withdrawing %s dollars", delta));
            break;
    }
    return operation;
}
```

Note: the example is purposely simple and doesn't benefit from using `enum` methods.

I have two `BankOperation` `PLUS` and `MINUS` with a `switch`. I get the `BankOperation` by `getBankOperation(5, 20);` so that I can proceed.

I was wondering if it is possible to use methods on the `enum` instead of `switch` so that I can get the `BankOperation` and adequate logging in chain by

```
BankOperation bankOperation = BankOperation.forOldAndNewAmount(5, 20).startProcessing();
```

where

> `forOldAndNewAmount(5, 20)` initializes the enum and makes the `delta` `15` a `private int delta` field of enum `BankOperation`
>
> `startProcessing()` is an abstract `method` of `BankOperation` which does `System.out.println(String.format("Adding/Withdrawing %s dollars", delta));` depending on the `BankOperation`

I found the most difficult is - printing the `delta` `15` in the `enum` body without putting it as a parameter of `startProcessing()` - returning the `PLUS` and `MINUS` `enum` itself in `startProcessing()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your actual example `getBankOperation()` is a processing which the `BankOperation` enum should be responsible.
You don't need a `Bank` instance to process it.
So just move this method as a static method of the enum :

```
enum BankOperation { PLUS, MINUS; 

     public static BankOperation getBankOperation(int oldAmount, int newAmount) {
            BankOperation operation = newAmount >= oldAmount ? BankOperation.PLUS : BankOperation.MINUS;
            int delta = Math.abs(newAmount - oldAmount);
            switch (operation) {
                case PLUS:
                    System.out.println(String.format("Adding %s dollars", delta));
                    break;
                case MINUS:
                    System.out.println(String.format("Withdrawing %s dollars", delta));
                    break;
            }
            return operation;
        }
    };
```

Now you can do :

```
BankOperation bankOperation = BankOperation.getBankOperation(5, 20);
```

Additionally this part could be moved in an enum method :

```
switch (operation) {
    case PLUS:
        System.out.println(String.format("Adding %s dollars", delta));
        break;
    case MINUS:
        System.out.println(String.format("Withdrawing %s dollars", delta));
        break;
}
```

It would give :

```
enum BankOperation {

    PLUS {
        public String getOutput(int delta) {
            return String.format("Adding %s dollars", delta);
        }
    },
    MINUS {

        @Override
        public String getOutput(int delta) {
            return String.format("Withdrawing %s dollars", delta);
        }
    };

    public abstract String getOutput(int delta);

    public static BankOperation getBankOperation(int oldAmount, int newAmount) {
        BankOperation operation = newAmount >= oldAmount ? BankOperation.PLUS : BankOperation.MINUS;
        int delta = Math.abs(newAmount - oldAmount);
        System.out.println(operation.getOutput(delta));
        return operation;
    }
}
```

---

About your comment :

> Is it possible you could let me know how to achieve "making the delta
>   a `private int delta` field of enum `BankOperation` when initializing it
>   with `forOldAndNewAmount(5, 20)` then I can call `startProcessing()` in
>   chain without making it a parameter"?

You should not do that because enums represent constant values. Overwritten values of enums during processing is unclear and may create side effects if your app is or become multi-threaded.
As alternative, you could use a class that wraps the `BankOperation` and the delta (`BankOperationComputed`) and that `forOldAndNewAmount()` returns.

`BankOperation getBankOperation()` would be so better named as `BankOperationComputed computeBankOperation()` :

```
public static BankOperationComputed computeBankOperation(int oldAmount, int newAmount) {
    BankOperation operation = newAmount >= oldAmount ? BankOperation.PLUS : BankOperation.MINUS;
    int delta = Math.abs(newAmount - oldAmount);
    return new BankOperationComputed(operation, delta);
}
```

**BankOperationComputed**

```
public class BankOperationComputed {
      private final BankOperation operation;
      private final int delta; 

      BankOperationComputed (BankOperation operation, int delta){
         this.operation = operation;
         this.delta = delta;
      }
      public void startProcessing(){
           System.out.println(operation.getOutput(delta));
      }
}
```

Now you can do that :

```
BankOperation.computeBankOperation(5, 20) // returns BankOperationComputed 
             .startProcessing();  // uses the enum under the hoods
```

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of `switch (operation)` and make it a `startProcessing()` enum strategy pattern method?

Comment: @Zizheng Wu Sure. I currently was updating my answer with this part.

Comment: Awesome, is it possible to make `System.out.println(operation.getOutput(delta));` part of an `abstract` `method` let's say `startProcessing()` of `BankOperation` so that I can call it in chain `BankOperation bankOperation = BankOperation.forOldAndNewAmount(5, 20).startProcessing();`

Comment: Sure but in your actual example  `startProcessing()` would need to have a parameter to print the delta. It creates some redundancy as elementary parts of delta are already passed to `forOldAndNewAmount()`. But maybe your example code differs a little too much from your real code...

Comment: I am thinking making the `delta` a `private int delta` field of `enum BankOperation` when initializing it with `forOldAndNewAmount(5, 20)` then I can call `startProcessing()` in chain without making it a parameter. It this feasible?

Comment: Feasible. But bad idea because enum represent constant values. Overwritten values of enum during processing is unclear and may create side effects if your app is or become multi-threaded.

Comment: Is it possible you could let me know how to achieve "making the `delta` a `private int delta` field of enum `BankOperation` when initializing it with `forOldAndNewAmount(5, 20)` then I can call `startProcessing()` in chain without making it a parameter"? I found it extremely difficult...

Comment: I don't want because it would be giving to you a really bad advise. I would propose another way. I updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178726/discussion-between-zizheng-wu-and-davidxxx).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like that:

```
public class Bank {

enum BankOperation { 
    PLUS("Adding %s dollars"), 
    MINUS("Withdrawing %s dollars");

    private final String msg;

    BankOperation(final String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }


    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
}

public BankOperation getBankOperation(int oldAmount, int newAmount) {
    BankOperation operation = newAmount >= oldAmount ? BankOperation.PLUS : BankOperation.MINUS;
    int delta = abs(newAmount - oldAmount);

    System.out.println(String.format(operation.getMsg(), delta));

    return operation;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The constants of an enum are subclasses of the (abstract) enum class itself. You can then do something like

```
public enum BankOperation {

    DEPOSIT {
        @Override
        public void execute(Bank bank, Amount amount) {
            // do something
        }
    },

    WITHDRAW {
        @Override
        public void execute(Bank bank, Amount amount) {
            // do something else
        }
    };

    public abstract void execute(Bank bank, Amount amount);
}

// called like 
BankOperation.DEPOSIT.execute(bank, amount);

// or
BankOperation operation;
...
operation.execute(bank, amount
```

Since the `enum` class is the (abstract) parent of each of its constant, . it is possible to add fields and constructors to the `enum`:

```
public enum BankOperation {

    DEPOSIT("Deposit") {
        @Override
        public void execute(Bank bank, Amount amount) {
            // do something
        }
    },

    WITHDRAW("Withdraw") {
        @Override
        public void execute(Bank bank, Amount amount) {
            // do something else
        }
    };

    private String name;

    private BankOperation(String theName) {
        this.name = theName;
    }

    public abstract void execute(Bank bank, Amount amount);

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Also adding static methods is helpful:

```
public enum BankOperation {

    DEPOSIT("Deposit") {
        ...
    },

    WITHDRAW("Withdraw") {
        ...
    };

    ...

    public static BankOperation get(Amount oldAmount, Amount newAmount) {
        // same amount being ignored for simplicity
        if (newAmount.isLessThan(oldAmount))
            return WITHDRAW;
        else
            return DEPOSIT;
    }
}
```